# Share a image between two websites by using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two web applications which need to show products' images, but how to let them share the images?

for example, I have websites with urls: http://www.test.com and http://backend.test.com

how could I upload images, store them and share with this two websites?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show images from another server in your web page...  If the image is at http://www.test.com/images/someimage.jpg, then you can link to that same image from http://backend.test.com.  Just use the full uri to the image, and not a relative path (such as "/images/someimage.jpg")

We do this with our shopping cart.. Our fulfillment program gets the product images from the actual shopping cart on our external web server.  It's not too difficult if you control both sites.